# How to ensure data isn't inserted into a table where the data already exists?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert

I've created a query which I want to insert the results into another table. It is going to be ran as a job every day, and data imported will still be kept in the result set. I don't want the data to be imported if it already exists in the target table. The query is listed below:

```
WITH cteUniquePages
(
CorrelationID,
Title,
URL,
HitDate,
TotalVisitsOnDate,
DontUseThisDate)
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
    CorrelationID,
    Title, 
    URL,
    HitDate,
    COUNT(HitDate) OVER (PARTITION BY URL, HitDate) 'TotalVisitsOnDate',
    CAST(LogTime AS date) 'DontUseThisDate'
    FROM
        (SELECT
        CorrelationId,
        UserLogin,
        LogTime,
        Title,
        CONCAT(
            (CASE 
                WHEN WebUrl <> '' THEN CONCAT(ServerUrl,'/') ELSE ServerUrl END), 
            WebUrl,DocumentPath) 'URL',
        CONCAT(
            CASE
                WHEN (LEN(DATEPART(day,LogTime)))=1 THEN CONCAT('0',DATEPART(day,LogTime)) END,
            CASE
                WHEN (LEN(DATEPART(day,LogTime)))=2 THEN (DATEPART(day,LogTime)) END,'-', 
            CASE 
                WHEN (LEN(DATEPART(month,LogTime)))=1 THEN CONCAT('0',DATEPART(month,LogTime)) END,
            CASE
                WHEN (LEN(DATEPART(month,LogTime)))=2 THEN (DATEPART(month,LogTime)) END,
            '-', DATEPART(year,LogTime)) 'HitDate'
        FROM WSS_Logging.dbo.RequestUsage
        WHERE UserLogin <> 'nt authority\iusr' 
        AND UserLogin <> 'i:0#.w|pfnet\zz_sharepoint13' 
        AND DocumentPath LIKE '%.aspx' 
        AND DocumentPath NOT LIKE '%/_layouts/%'
        AND UserLogin <> 'PFNET\E01BrownS'
        AND UserLogin <> 'i:0#.w|pfnet\sharepointtestacc1'
        GROUP BY UserLogin, WebUrl, DocumentPath, LogTime, Title, ServerUrl,CorrelationId) as a
),
    cteVisitsAllTime
    (
        CorrelationID,
        LogTime,
        Title,
        URL, 
        TotalVisits
    )
    AS
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
        CorrelationID,
        LogTime, 
        Title,
        URL,
        COUNT(URL) OVER (PARTITION BY URL) 'TotalVisits' 
        FROM(
            SELECT 
            CorrelationId,
            Title,
            CONCAT(
                (CASE 
                    WHEN WebUrl <> '' THEN CONCAT(ServerUrl,'/') ELSE ServerUrl END), 
                WebUrl,DocumentPath) 'URL', 
                LogTime 
            FROM WSS_Logging.dbo.RequestUsage
            WHERE UserLogin <> 'nt authority\iusr' 
            AND UserLogin <> 'i:0#.w|pfnet\zz_sharepoint13' 
            AND DocumentPath LIKE '%.aspx' 
            AND DocumentPath NOT LIKE '%/_layouts/%'
            AND UserLogin <> 'PFNET\E01BrownS'
            AND UserLogin <> 'i:0#.w|pfnet\sharepointtestacc1') as a
    ),
    cteVisitsLast7Days
    (
        CorrelationID,
        Title,
        URL, 
        TotalVisits
    )
    AS
    (
        SELECT
        CorrelationID, 
        Title,
        URL,
        COUNT(URL) OVER (PARTITION BY URL) 'TotalVisits' 
        FROM(
            SELECT 
            CorrelationId,
            Title,
            CONCAT(
                (CASE 
                    WHEN WebUrl <> '' THEN CONCAT(ServerUrl,'/') ELSE ServerUrl END), 
                WebUrl,DocumentPath) 'URL', 
                LogTime 
            FROM WSS_Logging.dbo.RequestUsage
            WHERE UserLogin <> 'nt authority\iusr' 
            AND UserLogin <> 'i:0#.w|pfnet\zz_sharepoint13' 
            AND DocumentPath LIKE '%.aspx' 
            AND DocumentPath NOT LIKE '%/_layouts/%'
            AND UserLogin <> 'PFNET\E01BrownS'
            AND UserLogin <> 'i:0#.w|pfnet\sharepointtestacc1') as a
            WHERE LogTime >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
    ),
    cteVisitsLast30Days
    (
        CorrelationID,
        Title,
        URL, 
        TotalVisits
    )
    AS
    (
        SELECT
        CorrelationID, 
        Title,
        URL,
        COUNT(URL) OVER (PARTITION BY URL) 'TotalVisits' 
        FROM(
            SELECT
            CorrelationId, 
            Title,
            CONCAT(
                (CASE 
                    WHEN WebUrl <> '' THEN CONCAT(ServerUrl,'/') ELSE ServerUrl END), 
                WebUrl,DocumentPath) 'URL', 
                LogTime 
            FROM WSS_Logging.dbo.RequestUsage
            WHERE UserLogin <> 'nt authority\iusr' 
            AND UserLogin <> 'i:0#.w|pfnet\zz_sharepoint13' 
            AND DocumentPath LIKE '%.aspx' 
            AND DocumentPath NOT LIKE '%/_layouts/%'
            AND UserLogin <> 'PFNET\E01BrownS'
            AND UserLogin <> 'i:0#.w|pfnet\sharepointtestacc1') as a
            WHERE LogTime >= DATEADD(day,-30, GETDATE())
    ),
    cteVisitsLastYear
    (
        CorrelationID,
        Title,
        URL, 
        TotalVisits
    )
    AS
    (
        SELECT
        CorrelationID, 
        Title,
        URL,
        COUNT(URL) OVER (PARTITION BY URL) 'TotalVisits' 
        FROM(
            SELECT
            CorrelationId, 
            Title,
            CONCAT(
                (CASE 
                    WHEN WebUrl <> '' THEN CONCAT(ServerUrl,'/') ELSE ServerUrl END), 
                WebUrl,DocumentPath) 'URL', 
                LogTime 
            FROM WSS_Logging.dbo.RequestUsage
            WHERE UserLogin <> 'nt authority\iusr' 
            AND UserLogin <> 'i:0#.w|pfnet\zz_sharepoint13' 
            AND DocumentPath LIKE '%.aspx' 
            AND DocumentPath NOT LIKE '%/_layouts/%'
            AND UserLogin <> 'PFNET\E01BrownS'
            AND UserLogin <> 'i:0#.w|pfnet\sharepointtestacc1') as a
            WHERE LogTime >= DATEADD(day,-365, GETDATE())
    )
SELECT DISTINCT 
cteUniquePages.Title,
cteUniquePages.URL,
cteUniquePages.HitDate,
cteUniquePages.TotalVisitsOnDate,
cteVisitsAllTime.TotalVisits 'All Time Visits',
cteVisitsLast7Days.TotalVisits 'Visits Last 7 Days',
cteVisitsLast30Days.TotalVisits 'Visits Last 30 Days',
cteVisitsLastYear.TotalVisits 'Visits Last Year',
cteUniquePages.DontUseThisDate
FROM cteUniquePages
LEFT JOIN cteVisitsAllTime ON cteVisitsAllTime.CorrelationID = cteUniquePages.CorrelationID
LEFT JOIN cteVisitsLast7Days ON cteVisitsLast7Days.CorrelationID = cteUniquePages.CorrelationID
LEFT JOIN cteVisitsLast30Days ON cteVisitsLast30Days.CorrelationID = cteUniquePages.CorrelationID
LEFT JOIN cteVisitsLastYear ON cteVisitsLastYear.CorrelationID = cteUniquePages.CorrelationID
ORDER BY DontUseThisDate DESC, cteUniquePages.URL
```

Answer (score 5):

There are a few options for this:

1. Add a `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM <target_table> WHERE <matching_predicates> )` clause to the `INSERT ... SELECT ...` statement. though make sure you test with real data patters as with a relatively complex.
2. `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to the target table and add a `WHERE target_table.primarykey IS NULL` clause - this will be false if a matching row is not found by the outer join. Usually this produces the same plan as `WHERE NOT EXISTS` though it may vary for complex queries. If there is a performance difference (I have seen the `JOIN` variant perform better then `WHERE NOT EXISTS` though that was a few engine versions ago) go with the query that produces the better plan, otherwise go with what you find easier to read and maintain.
3. Use [`MERGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead of plain `INSERT`, though this is most useful if you want to update existing rows rather then just not duplicate them.

Answer (score 2):

There are no inserts or table structures in your sample query, so I'm going to use a simpler version to explain it:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Source
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    Title VARCHAR(50),
    URL VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Source(Title, URL) VALUES ('Stack Overflow', 'https://stackoverflow.com');
INSERT INTO dbo.Source(Title, URL) VALUES ('Database Administrators', 'https://dba.stackexchange.com');    

CREATE TABLE dbo.Target
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    Title VARCHAR(50),
    URL VARCHAR(50)
);

/* Here's the data you want to copy from Source to Target: */
INSERT INTO dbo.Target
(
    Title,
    URL
)
SELECT s.Title,
       s.URL
FROM dbo.Source s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Target t
        ON s.Title = t.Title
           AND s.URL = t.URL
WHERE t.ID IS NULL;

/* You can run the above repeatedly, and then check to see if there are duplicates: */
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Target;
```

In my example, I used a left outer join technique and I joined on both fields (Title and URL). I didn't join on ID because I assume it's going to be different in both tables.

In your real-life scenario, as you're copying data, pick as few fields as you can that represent what's truly unique - as in, how you're going to identify if the row already exists or not. The more fields you pick, and the larger your datatypes, the worse it's going to perform.

Your field list is:

```
cteUniquePages.Title,
cteUniquePages.URL,
cteUniquePages.HitDate,
cteUniquePages.TotalVisitsOnDate,
cteVisitsAllTime.TotalVisits 'All Time Visits',
cteVisitsLast7Days.TotalVisits 'Visits Last 7 Days',
cteVisitsLast30Days.TotalVisits 'Visits Last 30 Days',
cteVisitsLastYear.TotalVisits 'Visits Last Year',
cteUniquePages.DontUseThisDate
```

I'm guessing that only Title, URL, and HitDate are what make rows unique (and maybe DontUseThisDate). As hit metrics change over time, management is going to ask you to reload the data. So what you probably want is to delete rows that exist for that date range first, then use this technique.

As you read about how to do that kind of reload work, you're also going to come across SQL Server's MERGE statement. Read [Aaron Bertrand's list of MERGE gotchas](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) before you do that.

Answer (score 0):

One option, assuming that you are not using all columns to determine uniqueness, is to create a Unique Index that has the `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` option/property enabled. When `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` is enabled, duplicate rows are simply excluded from the `INSERT` operation rather than having the operation throw an error and automatically roll back. The only down-side that I am aware of with this option is that when duplicates are excluded, a warning is sent back to the client that some older Database drivers are not able to handle and will error. But the nice thing is, in a set-based operation, if there are duplicates, the first row will succeed and the rest will be ignored. This might allow you to remove the `DISTINCT` from your query (and if you are just inserting the data, then also remove the `ORDER BY`).

```sql
CREATE TABLE #UniqueTest
(
  [ID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  [Col1] INT NULL,
  [Col2] INT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [UIX_#UniqueTest_Col1]
  ON #UniqueTest ([Col1])
  WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON);

INSERT INTO #UniqueTest ([Col1], [Col2]) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO #UniqueTest ([Col1], [Col2]) VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO #UniqueTest ([Col1], [Col2]) VALUES (3, 1);
INSERT INTO #UniqueTest ([Col1], [Col2]) VALUES (NULL, 1);
INSERT INTO #UniqueTest ([Col1], [Col2]) VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO #UniqueTest ([Col1], [Col2]) VALUES (NULL, 1);
```

The output of those INSERT statements is:

```
(1 row affected)

(1 row affected)

(1 row affected)

(1 row affected)
Duplicate key was ignored.

(0 rows affected)
Duplicate key was ignored.

(0 rows affected)
```

As you can see, the final two statements were (mostly) silently ignored (except for the "*Duplicate key was ignored*" warning).

If we look at the current rows, there are only 4. We will also multiply by 2 just to see the values that we will attempt to insert next. Two of those values already exist (i.e. `NULL` and `2`) and the other two are not yet in the table (i.e. `4` and `6`).

```sql
SELECT tmp.[Col1], tmp.[Col1] * 2
FROM   #UniqueTest tmp;
/*
NULL   NULL
1      2
2      4
3      6
*/
```

Now we can insert them in a set-based operation. I added a `CROSS JOIN` to force duplicates within the set being inserted, and yet there is no `DISTINCT` being used.

```sql
INSERT INTO #UniqueTest ([Col1], [Col2])
  SELECT tmp.[Col1] * 2, 1
  FROM   #UniqueTest tmp
  CROSS JOIN #UniqueTest tmp2;
```

The "Messages" tab has the following in it:

```
Duplicate key was ignored.

(2 rows affected)
```

If we view the contents of the table again, we can see that the rows are still unique for `Col1`. We also see that the Identity value has gaps, indicating that the values were reserved prior to SQL Server checking the Unique Index to determine that those rows could not actually be inserted. Just something to be aware of.

```sql
SELECT * FROM #UniqueTest;
/*
1     1       1
2     2       1
3     3       1
4     NULL    1
15    4       1
19    6       1
*/
```

And, just to prove that the "*Duplicate key was ignored*" message is really a warning and not an error, we can attempt to trap errors as follows:

```sql
BEGIN TRY
  INSERT INTO #UniqueTest ([Col1], [Col2]) VALUES (NULL, 1);
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  PRINT ERROR_NUMBER();
  PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();
END CATCH;
```

The "Messages" tab has the following in it:

```
Duplicate key was ignored.

(0 rows affected)
```

**In your specific case,** I shall assume that the number of hits per time period columns are not being used for uniqueness, and thus you should use the following:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [UIX_MyTableName_Title_URL_HitDate]
  ON [SchemaName].[MyTableName] ([Title], [URL], [HitDate])
  WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)
  ON [FileGroupName];
```

I was not sure how the `DontUseThisDate` column factored into the uniqueness. If it is needed for uniqueness, then it is easy to add it to the above statement.

---

Please note that this silent ignoring of duplicate rows is for `INSERT` operations only, and does not affect `UPDATE` operations.

```sql
UPDATE ut
SET    ut.[Col1] = 4
FROM   #UniqueTest ut
WHERE  ut.[ID] = 4;
```

> Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line XXXXX
>     Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.#UniqueTest' with unique index 'UIX_#UniqueTest_Col1'. The duplicate key value is (4).
>      The statement has been terminated.

---

For more info, please see: [CREATE INDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql)